# Создание нескольких git репозиториев для одной папки с разными пользователями

Tags: git, github, репозиторий, проекты, git-репозиторий

Смотрел видеурок [Git курс. Конфигурация](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWiqh6YUUS8&list=PLDyvV36pndZFHXjXuwA_NywNrVQO0aQqb&index=3). Там создается пустой репозиторий с помощью команды `git init`. Затем в нем задаются имя пользователя и email c помощью команд

```
git config user.name "Ilya Kantor"
git config user.email "iliakan@gmail.com"
```

После в видео на 2:00 - 2:15 сказано, что у разных пользователей в различных директориях могут находиться разные проекты. У меня возник вопрос, а можно ли для одной папки создать несколько репозиториев (с помощью команды `git init` или какой-нибудь другой) с разными значениями name и email в секции user файла `/.git/config`, т.е. с разными пользователями?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519446/6944845

Comment: Нет. Просто потому, что у вас не может быть два разных файла `.git/config` с одним и тем же путём и именем.